# phpmyadmin working with mysql connection access

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin, host

I've a **database server** where currently operators are able to **access in 2 different ways**:

1) Roles with "sensible permissions" are **restricted by specific IP of a VPN.**

2) Roles with more secure permissions are **not restricted by IP but just by password.**

Currently all db users are accessing via desktop clients such as SQLYog / Heidi etc.

Now i would offer them a remote **phpmyadmin panel** instead.

But i've noticed that **phpmyadmin doesn't let my VPN users to login** since MySQL server connection are executed with phpmyadmin host instead.

**Is there any way to solve it continuing to use the [mysql connection access](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connection-access.html)** system?

Answer (score 0):

Phpmyadmin looks like proxy for request of end-users. So you should move connection access system rules to interaction between end-user and phpmyadmin.
I showed this offer on the image below
[Comparison between old and new access system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NZ9Q.png)

Comment: i don't think this is an answere, this is just what i've already explained in my post.

Comment: You can install phpmyadmin locally for every user and change default config to work with remote host. Maybe this can work for you and you can use in this case your mysql connection access system

Comment: phpmyadmin should replace SQLYog / Heidi etc as local client to allow my users to access via web. It's not an acceptable solution